# How do I change the order of my favourites?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Without un-favouriting all of my current favourites, and then favouriting them again, is there any way to change the order that my favourites appear in?

Comment: I don't think you can, but I hope I"m proved wrong.

Comment: As an added note, I just realised, favourites aren't ordered in the order you favourited them, they're ordered alphabetically like the rest of your inventory.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't. However, on the PC version it is possible to assign shortcuts to certain favorite items.

Press Q to bring up the quick menu. Then, hold down a number key (1 trough 8) while hovering over a item or spell for a second. Swap between items during gameplay by tapping the assigned number key.

Comment: I did not know about this!  Very neat.

Comment: What? Hotkeys? Awesome!

Comment: You sir, have made my day.

Comment: There is no quickmenu when I press Q. Do I have to enable it first or what? I am level 4 and just finished the The Golden Claw quest.

Comment: @Bora In your inventory, favorite an item and it will appear in in this menu.