# Is there a way to bind items to the number keys in Skyrim?

Tags: pc, the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm less than impressed with the favorites menu for quick swapping spells in the middle of a fight. Is there anyway I can bind them to the number pad on the keyboard?

Comment: The way ive been playing spells can only go into your right hand (sword hand) if you have the perk that corresponds to the spells skill level. Bound sword is interesting as the perk is second level and you can dual wield them, however upon unlocking the perk Conjuration Dual Casting this is no longer the case, not sure if its a bug but bound sword will refuse to be equipped in both hands. I use Bound Sword all the time, my level 24 Breton has no weapons and uses only bound, I have yet to find a one handed weapon that does more damage.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

> Press Q to bring up the quick menu. Then, hold down a number key (1 trough 8)
>   while hovering over a item or spell for a second. Swap between items during 
>   gameplay by tapping the assigned number key.

Courtesy of [Xenox's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/34989/how-do-i-change-the-order-of-my-favourites/35000#35000).

Comment: Oh thank Akatosh, having no quick keys was driving me around the bend. A spell-casting archer is still possible!

Comment: Could you expand on how you choose which hand the item or spell goes to when using the number buttons?

Comment: @Fabian It seems to default to weapons going into the right hand, and shields/spells going into the left hand. I haven't found a way around this, except in the case of switching from a 2H item. If you press the key the 2H is bound to while wielding the 2H, you'll go back to your previous dual-wield setup.

Comment: Is there a way to (maybe programmatically, with macros or aliases?) bind one key into multiple actions? For example, equip A in left hand and B in right hand with one key?

Comment: Apparently you can bind to the left hand with Shift + <number>.

Comment: @Seven I'm not able to reproduce that behavior.

Answer (score 12):

Woot.
Google never ceases to amaze me.

After reading this I figured out how to get a somewhat desired effect.
Pressing the key twice will essentially put it in both hands.
Such as bound sword, first in Left Hand for me (Right Mouse, I might end up reversing the mouse binds -_-) and then in Right Hand (Left Mouse).
So I can dual wield Bound Swords by pressing the key twice.

So far I have figured out the following:

Physical things go into your Right Hand first (Left Mouse), Magical things go into your Left Hand first (Right Mouse).

So if you bind Bound Sword to 1 and some physical sword to 2.
Pressing 1,2 with nothing equipped as a weapon will put the bound sword in your Left Hand (RM) and the Physical Sword in your Right Hand (LM).
If you press 1 twice, this will put Bound Sword in both hands.
I don't have 2 physical swords atm so I can't clarify if binding another one to 3, and then pressing 2,3 will cause you to dual wield them.

But feel free to experiment on your own!
and thank you for answering my question -:D

Comment: +1 I didn't realize that you could double-tap to dual wield a weapon. Also, welcome to the site.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got the **SkyUI** mod installed you'll need to first *disable* the mod before launching the game. Then follow the directions by favoring items, spells, potions, etc and then pressing the number key you want to assign (1: bow, 2: sword, 3: shield, etc). Save (preferably a new save), exit the game, reenable SkyUI and continue from the last save. Now you'll still be able to thankfully use the number keys **1**, **2**, **3**, etc without having to go either in to inventory *or* the favorites menu. Unless they create a fix you'll have to keep exiting the game and repeating this each time you change your favorites *or* perhaps there is a more refined GUI mod for the menus? The main thing is at least you won't be asking your enemies to wait half a minute in the middle of combat while you whip out a healing potion.