# Quick weapon cycle

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was planning to try play Skyrim on the PC again. The first time I played, I find the menu system extremely annoying. Especially with regards to cycling/swapping through weapons.

It seems to be a common idiom in PC games to cycle through available weapons with the mouse wheel. Is it possible in Skyrim to do so, with the help of some mods perhaps?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't look to be a way to bind to the mouse wheel.

The best way is to add them to favorites:

1. Favorite your stuff with F
2. Open the favorite menu with Q and assign numbers 1~8

ONE-HANDED WEAPON + SHIELD Combo : Press the corresponding hotkeys in any order.

ONE-HANDED WEAPON + SPELL : Equip the weapon first then the spell (you can then cycle through other spells and the weapon will stay in your right hand)

DUAL-WIELDING SPELLS : Simply press the corresponding hotkey twice. As far as I know, all spells can be dual-wielded.

As for dual-wielding weapons, there seems to be two methods.

Automatic Dual-Wield (SAME WEAPON ONLY) : With the favorites menu open, highlight the weapon you want to dual-wield (must have a [x] next to the name where x is the item quantity). Equip it as you normally would (we're not assigning a hotkey yet) THEN right-click. If done correctly it should now say "LR" next to the item's name. Now you can hotkey them !

Manual Dual-Wield : unfortunately, hotkeys don't seem to be supported with this but I'll post it anyway. Basically you'll want to open the Favorites menu, equip your right-hand weapon first with E (or whatever you have assigned to Activate) then highlight what will be your offhand weapon and right-click anywhere in the screen. Yeah it's kind of a pain as hotkeys clear the "L" but at least you don't have to click ON the weapon's name.

The above is from [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/615805-the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim/60983686)

There's a video showing how [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZHtmILlxQ4Y)

This question has been answered [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35316/how-do-i-quickly-switch-between-weapons-and-spells)