# Why am I snubbing the bow?

Tags: pc, the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have four favourites that are [bound to hotkeys](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35107/is-there-a-way-to-bind-items-to-the-number-keys-in-skyrim):

1. Long bow (3)
2. Iron sword (2)
3. Flame
4. Sparks

While I have a sword in my right hand and Flame in my left I can switch to the bow just fine by pressing <kbd>1</kbd>, but when I switch away from the bow and back to the sword and Flame by pressing <kbd>2</kbd> my character apparently decides that bows suck and the hotkey unbinds.

I know that this is highly likely to be a bug. Why I ask is in case I am missing something obvious (or not-so-obvious) that's causing this that *isn't* a bug. Considering my opinion of the Skyrim menu interface so far, it's also likely that it's just me and Skyrim having a disagreement about how it's supposed to work.

Even if it's a bug, confirming the bug would also be helpful. Even better would be the exact configuration that triggers the bug and figuring out a workaround. I want my bow on a hotkey!

Comment: I am having the same problem - I'm pretty sure it's a bug.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Oh yes i had that one too. There is a simple way of fixing this... you have 3 bows of the same kind. Sell 2 and keep only one. If you hotkey with only one of a kind the hotkeys will work.

Comment: Too much of a good thing, eh? I'll try to confirm this when I get back to my Skyrim install. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @SevenSidedDie It is strange yes, but why would you need more then 1 of the same? It is not as if they can break...

Comment: @RafaelCelerier Early on you probably haven't found anything unique in your travels. It wasn't until level 20 or so I bothered to enchant an item (and thus name it uniquely). So if you are using an iron warhammer, you are going to have several of those in no time.

Comment: @Rafael For their sale value. Looting bodies results in a lot of duplicate items. I just haven't got back to town to unload yet.

Comment: This is it exactly.  The game loses track of which bow is hotkeyed when it rejoins the duplicates in your inventory.  The keybind doesn't break, the "item" no longer exists.  Sometimes you can avoid this by hotkey'ing the entire stack while none of them are equipped, but your best bet is to improve or enchant one (a longbow can be improved with a chunk of firewood!) so it becomes unique compared to the others.